# Is URL rewrite / routing (mod_rewrite) really necessary for a framework?

Tags: php, frameworks, url-routing, conceptual

I've been writing PHP code for years. And now I have plenty of reusable modules -- for me at least.  A typical classic-old-style developer :D. But now almost everybody using *baked instant* framework, and my modules not *reusable* anymore --to some extent. Most of current *famous* framework such CI, Zend, Cake, etc. and also should-be-simpler micro-framework such as Fat-free, Silex, MicroMVC, etc. utilize method called URL routing / URL rewrite or such.

But... do you think this *fancy* URL routing is REALLY necessary?

Let's consider this:

- How much work needed to process this fancy method of complexities? Regular expression parsing uses relatively heavy computing isn't it? Is it worthed?
- How often we write URL address / type it manually? Instead of click bookmarks and/or hyperlink?
- Is it really search-engine friendly? I mean doesn't it OK for search engines indexing URL params?
- Why BIG sites such as Google, Facebook, etc still using "path?var1=val1&var2=val2&..."?
- How about different settings on different web servers? Apache/IIS/Nginx/Ligthy? Such as porting .htaccess to web.config and to another?? Doesn't it make more problem than more solution? (for debugging, etc)

What do you think? Should we keep on with that *fancy* URL routing? Or we better go back to [web] nature with [simpler] request params? Any respond appreciated.

Comment: You really want to type "?site=admin" and not just "/admin"?

Comment: @Abenil: no. I almost NEVER type an URL. I click a bookmark, a link, go to selected URL by pop-up menu, or copy-paste it. That's why I think pretty URL is NOT necessary. ;-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- computation costs of running URL through regular expressions arr mitigated by use of APC
- it is not about manual URL entry
- yes, it has impact in context of SEO
- because they have to save each flop, your site does not have billions of requests per day
- this is actually why [front controllers](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/frontController.html) are used instead of .htaccess for parsing URLs

That should take care of your "points".

And yes, we should keep on using "pretty URL" because a lot of people glance at the full URL, before they click on the link. People fee l safer, when they see the full and understandable URL.

Also, quite a lot of professional PHP developers try to avoid the *popular* frameworks. Mostly because quality of said frameworks are really, really bad (even Symfony2, which is considered to be one of best available, has issues) in terms of code quality.

Just because you use a framework, it does not make your application better. Instead you should be focusing on proper OOP, following the SOLID principles and adhering to Law of Demeter. MVC is just another design pattern, which actually solves separation of presentation of domain business logic.

If you want to learn about MVC, read [GUI Architectures](http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/uiArchs.html) by *Martin Fowler*.

Comment: So... is it means if we expecting billions of requests per day, pretty URL routing doesn't necessary/expected anymore?

Comment: It is not about what is expected or necessary. When you can save few million $ per year, by avoiding the additional computation costs, it is the responsible solution. If you make next Google or next Facebook, you also might have to consider such a step.

Comment: I see... for addition, people loves to compare framework's benchmarks. Nevertheless they do or not going to make site with billions or even millions visitors. ;-)

Comment: If you want to "benchmark" frameworks, use *PHP CodeSniffer*, *PHP Mess Detector* and/or *PHP Depend*.

Answer (score 3):

Ultimately, it comes down to the design architecture, specifically with these, [MVC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller)

> How much work needed to process this fancy method of complexities? Regular expression parsing uses relatively heavy computing isn't it? Is it worthed?

While there is a bit of a cost for starting up the rewrite engine, the majority of these frameworks don't use regular expressions in their routing. It simply blindly routes every request that doesn't map to an existing resource to the controller (e.g. index.php) and lets it figure it out. That being said, there's probably a bigger impact on running php than there is on the rewrite engine.

> How often write URL address / type it manually? Instead of click bookmarks and/or hyperlink?

Not sure what the relevance of this is. Is it easier to type (or remember) `http://domain.com/post/intro-to-apache` than it is to type `http://domain.com/post.php?post_id=141`?

> Is it really search-engine friendly? I mean doesn't it OK for search engines indexing URL params?

Yes it really is, and it makes a big impact. Not just that, it's easier for people to see what the link is.

> Why BIG sites such as Google, Facebook, etc still using "path?var1=val1&var2=val2&..."?

There's a difference between having something like a `post_id` in the URI vs a `q` for a query string. The former is dynamically accessing existing content, the latter is dynamic form input which can *be anything the user enters*.

EDIT: Just a note, Facebook *does* do URL rewriting, so does Wikipedia. It's to make the URL human readable as well as better SEO.

> How about different settings on different web servers? Apache/IIS/Nginx/Ligthy? Such as porting .htaccess to web.config and to another?? Doesn't it make more problem than more solution? (for debugging, etc)

The routing rules are very very simple. And the frameworks provide it for widely used webservers. If you want to do something custom, obviously you have to work around these routing rules, but you'd have to be at least competently fluent in the webserver's rewrite engine in the first place.

Comment: how about standardizing simpler request params? Such as "?do=thing&on=item" or something else simlar to SQL statements. It can become better solution isn't it? A faster, efficient & more port-able framework.

Comment: @mbahMu The pretty URL bit is kind of a separate thing from the MVC framework. In some frameworks you can even turn it off (like mediawiki, though wikipedia has URL rewriting turned on), it's just a matter of how links are being generated. The main reasons for it is to make it look nicer for humans and for SEO reasons.

Comment: thank you. That is exactly what I like to know for sure. That pretty URL is *not* obligatory feature for MVC frameworks as it *seems* to be.

Answer (score 0):

If nothing else, haveing nice URL's is something that used (and probably partly is still) important to search engines. It is also nicer if you send the link to another person.